# BaseX list specific documents for database

Tags: basex

When building a database in BaseX, can I provide a list of documents to be added? (Or a list of documents *not* to be added?)

I'm working from a directory structure that contains both the documents of interest, as well as older versions that I want to exclude. It would be a big hassle to change the whole directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty database, and then subsequently loop over those documents you want to add and run the [`ADD` command](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands#ADD) for each of them.

Alternatively, you could add them from within XQuery. Query for the files you want to add using the [file module](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/File_Module), and add them running using [`db:add(...)`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Module#db:add).

Comment: Thanks.
Does this mean I need to list all the file names (a couple of hundred) in a `for` loop comman? I would prefer to maintain some sort of manifest file where I list either the files to be indexed, or files to be ignored.
It would also be good if I could exclude files based on a regex for their file path. E.g. exclude all the ones with 'backup' in the path.

Comment: You don't need to hardcode such a list -- simply generate it using any kind of filters, either from your shell or from within BaseX/XQuery. In other words, list all files (using common unix tools like `find`) and filter it ("list of documents not to be added") either using `find` filters` or `grep`, ... Passing to BaseX is easy using `xargs`. When you're on Windows, similar mechanics exist, using PowerShell seems a reasonable thing to do (the basic command interpreter is not actually comfortable to use).